# Take values from URL with jquery, not php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
http://h3gsat.altervista.org/DettagliCompleto.php?id=4567
```

I tried to take the `id` parameter, but I failed.
I have to make this work in javascript (jquery) not php, but I don't know how I can do.

Comment: Hey, did you tried solution I posted?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// http://h3gsat.altervista.org/DettagliCompleto.php?id=4567
var value_of_id=$.urlParam('id');        // 6

console.log(value_of_id);
```

Here is demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUbE5/)

**EDIT: Pure javascript solution**

```
function urlParam(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// http://h3gsat.altervista.org/DettagliCompleto.php?id=4567
var value_of_id=urlParam('id');        // 6

console.log(value_of_id);
```

Comment: the `$.` is just to make it look like you use `jquery` right?

Comment: OP can ignore it. Afterall jQuery is javascript  library itself.

Comment: Btw, it won't work with url like this: `?dog=1&dog=2&dog=4`. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It will work for OP's URL, for same repeated parameters it won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  var str = $(location).attr('href');   
  alert(str);
  var myString = str.substr(str.indexOf("?id=")+4);
  alert(myString);


});
```